# Exact Change UVA

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I was solving following problem.

[image]

and its solution algorithm is at http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/UVa_11517

Pseudo-algorithm :

```
int dp[30001];

dp[0] = 0;
for (int i=1; i<=30000; i++)
    dp[i] = INFINITE;

for each coin C do
    for (int v = 30001 - C - 1; v >= 0; v--)
        if (dp[v] < INFINITE)
            dp[v+C] = min(dp[v+C], dp[v]+1);
```

But I think that its solution is wrong.
Lets take case where coin denomination are:

```
Coins = [500,1000,1500]
```

and for `price = 3000`. According to above solution, its answer would be `3000 with 3 coins`. But 3000 can be obtained from 2 coins of `1500`.
Please let me know whether this solution is wrong or right.

Comment: Questions on stackoverflow.com should not cite links to external web sites that can stop working at any time, rendering the question meaningless. You need to edit your question, and restate it without using links to external sites.

Comment: How can you pay with two coins of `1500` if there is only one in the input?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik added question.

Comment: @CampuChip You can use any number of coins. added problem statement in question itself.

Comment: @EmptyData the way I read it, 3 lines of input mean you have 3 bills or coins, with the specified denomination, not that you have _unlimited_ amounts of each of them. Looking at the solution, that does not seem to be what they have in mind though, in which case I agree their solution is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The proposed solution is correct because you do not have an unlimited number of coins of each denomination:

> [I]t is often helpful to bring cash.
>
> The following n lines each contain one integer, the value in cents of each bill or coin that you have.

That is why the loop in the proposed solution decreases:

```
for (int v = 30001 - C - 1; v >= 0; v--)
```

This avoids using the same coin twice because when it looks at `dp[v]` to construct `dp[v+C]`, `dp[v]` has been constructed without using the current coin C.

Additionally, to allow using any coin any number of times, reversing this loop would be enough:

```
for (int v = 0; v <= 30001 - C - 1; v++)
```